# Problemas con VScode al ejecutar un programa de python

Tags: python, vscode, test, pruebas-unitarias, unittest

Cuando ejecuto un programa de pruebas en Python, me da el siguiente error y no me permite ejecutar ningún programa, ni siquiera el más básico.

[image: Error]

Comment: Quizás este [enlace](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/1882) te sea de ayuda